# How to add Onlick on countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I wanna give this countdown code, an onclick button.

When I click on the button, it starts.

How can i do it?

Thanks

```js
var targetURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
var countdownfrom = 10

var currentsecond = document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML = countdownfrom + 1

function countredirect() {
  if (currentsecond != 1) {
    currentsecond -= 1
    document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML = currentsecond
  } else {
    window.location = targetURL
    return
  }
  setTimeout("countredirect()", 1000)
}

countredirect()
```

```html
<span id="redirect"></span>
```

Comment: I believe your code could be improved. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451311/6313073) is my suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a viable option:

1. You set the **`innerHTML`** of the **`redirect`** element on load.
2. When the button is clicked, it executes the function every second and resets the counter.
3. As long as the countdown is **`> 0`** decrement it.
4. If it's **`0`** stop the **`interval`**.

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var
  interval,
  countdown = 10,
  redir = document.getElementById("redirect"),
  targetURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/",
  reset = function () {
    redir.innerHTML = countdown;
  };
  
/* Set the countdown to the redirect element. */
window.onload = reset;

/* When the button is clicked... */
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
  var
    button = this,
    counter = countdown;
  
  /* Clear the interval to start anew. */
  clearInterval(interval);
  this.innerHTML = "Restart";
  
  /* The interval. */
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter) redir.innerHTML = --counter;
    else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      button.innerHTML = "Start";
    }
  }, 1000);

  /* Reset. */
  reset();
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<span id = "redirect"></span>
<button id = "button">Start</button>
```

Comment: This allows multiple clicks of the button, producing probably unexpected results. ;-)

Comment: Nice one @RobG :) I added a **`clearInterval`** before setting it in case the OP wants the countdown to restart on each click.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return countredirect();">Item</a>
```